# I want to connect my service

Tags: web-services, ubuntu, docker, service, connection

> What happened

: It can't be connected to be made my service on Web browser.

> What you expected to happen

: Connect to my service

> How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible)

:
First, I made 'my-deploy.yaml' like this.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: my-deploy-name
spec:
 replicas: 3
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: my-deploy
  spec:
   containers:
   - name: mycontainer
     image: alicek106/composetest:balanced_web
     ports:
     - containerPort: 80
```

And then, I made 'my-service.yaml' like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: my-service-name
spec:
 ports:
  - name: my-deploy-svc
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
 type: LoadBalancer
 externalIPs:
  - 104.196.161.33
 selector:
  app: my-deploy
```

So, I created the deployment and service,

```
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>           443/TCP          6d
my-service-name   LoadBalancer   10.106.31.254   104.196.161.33   8080:32508/TCP   5d

NAME               DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
my-deploy-name     3         3         3            3           6d
```

and try to connect 104.196.161.33:8080 , 104.196.161.33:32508 on Chrome Browser. But It doesn't work.
What should I do?

> Environment
>   :

Kubernetes version :
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.1", GitCommit:"f38e43b221d08850172a9a4ea785a86a3ffa3b3a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-11T23:27:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.1", GitCommit:"f38e43b221d08850172a9a4ea785a86a3ffa3b3a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-11T23:16:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Cloud provider or hardware configuration: VM on ubuntu 16.04.LTS

OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release): ubuntu 16.04.LTS

Kernel : Linux master 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Install tools: Docker-CE v17.06

Others:

```
kubectl get node
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
master    Ready     master    6d        v1.8.1
node1     Ready     <none>    6d        v1.8.1
node2     Ready     <none>    6d        v1.8.1

ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ba:93:a2:f2
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ens160    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:80:ab:14
          inet addr:39.119.118.176  Bcast:39.119.118.255  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe80:ab14/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9581474 errors:0 dropped:473 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4928331 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1528509917 (1.5 GB)  TX bytes:4020347835 (4.0 GB)

flannel.1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c6:b5:ef:90:ea:8f
          inet addr:10.244.0.0  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:184 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:44750027 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44750027 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:13786966091 (13.7 GB)  TX bytes:13786966091 (13.7 GB)
```

※ P.S : Could you recommend the Web service example on docker & kubernetes to me?

Comment: What is the response of `104.196.161.33:32508` ??? a 404 ?? Can you please provide response for `10.106.31.254:32508` ?

Comment: @200OK there is no response because it can't be connected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, external-IP was allocated by GCE automatically. It doesn't need to be set manually in yaml configuration. Thus, if you discovered that EXTERNAL-IP is  status in output of command "kubectl get svc ${service-name}", it may means works what you intended.

(but I'm not sure whether specifying external-IP in configuration works..)
And as I know, service of LoadBalancer type works only in cloud integration, which supports such functionality.

PS. I guess you are trying to test contents in "Let's starting Docker" in Republic of Korea, if you so, kindly contact me by e-mail address or twitter :D
I can reply you directly because I'm author of that book.